# Delete Ubuntu 18.04 with dual boot with linux mint on SSD

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, delete

I have installed linux ubuntu but had some problem with the divers so i installed linux mint but now they are splitted in 2 halves on my SSD and want to delete ubuntu now.
I am new to linux so i dont know how to do it and searching on google only gives me this situation but with windows instead.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete or concatenate a partition, you can use `gparted`.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gparted
sudo gparted
```

to remove ubuntu entry from `grub` bootloader( if installed ), run

```
sudo update-grub
```